# Accessing proper resource bundle in Spring Framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am trying to access a resource bundle using Spring framework (WebFlow). A messages.properties file and accordingly messages_ar_AE.properties file are kept in the classpath from where the Spring Framework access the resource bundle.

The code in invoked from a xhtml file using the JSTL resourceBundle attribute.

```
<myCustom:includedInSetValidator set="5.0, 5.0.1, 5.1" 
                            validationMessage="#{resourceBundle['jboss.version.error']}" />
```

But irrespective of locale, the `"#{resourceBundle['jboss.version.error']}"` always fetches the default text, i.e; from English;

As I learned from some forums I got an hint that I need to handle this using LocaleChangeInterceptor or some other predefined classes. Once the Spring Locale is set, the proper resource bundle will be loaded by default, and hence solving my problem.

I need a way to change the Spring Framework Locale programatically to set the Locale. How do I achieve this programatically ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reached the solution for the problem.

Continuing from my question, when Spring Framework encounters a JSTL expression like `"#{resourceBundle['jboss.version.error']}"` by default it looks for message.properties file in the classpath, unless a resource bundle is defined explicitly.

When trying to fetch the proper resource bundle, the framework looks at the at the locale it is set to. As the locale of Spring Framework was not set in my case, it was not fetching me the expected resource bundle. Out of available options i chose Spring LocaleResolver

I modified existing JSF Custom ViewHandler in my application, where I added code to set the locale of Spring Framework.

```
public Locale calculateLocale(FacesContext arg0) {

HttpServletRequest request  = (HttpServletRequest)arg0.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        HttpServletResponse response  = (HttpServletResponse)arg0.getExternalContext().getResponse();

LocaleResolver localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request);

localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, **setYourLocaleHere**);

}
```

The story just doesn't end here, setting the locale in locale resolver this way would throw the error:

```
Cannot change HTTP accept header – use a different locale resolution strategy
```

Refer [Cannot change HTTP accept header error](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/cannot-change-http-accept-header-use-a-different-locale-resolution-strategy/)

To overcome this, one should include

```
<bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>
```

in the Spring configuration file.

And now the desired locale of the Spring Framework is set.

There could possibly a better solution than what I did. One can also suggest their solutions if any.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this multiple ways as outlined [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver) in the doc.

Comment: Raghuram, thanks for your suggestion. I had already gone through the documentation, but wasn't quite sure of how to implement it, as i am new to this framework.